# Show Deleted Records point in time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema, sql-delete

I want to write a function / stored procedure where I want to pass a date and time and get all the rows that exist for a particular date and time, if records were deleted after that date and time it should show them otherwise no.

Let's say I have a table students (`id, name, createdate`) with 100 rows today morning before 10:30 am, I delete 30 records today at 10:30 am and I run my function with today's date and time 10:35, it should return 70 records, but if I run the function with an older date like today's date at 09:30 am, it should return 100 records.

Please reply with the best possible solutions for this in SQL Server. I don't want to create a separate table of deleted items and then compare and show with that.

Comment: You have `database-administration` as a tag, where you looking for something in SSMS?

Comment: You don't state your version of SQL Server. If 2016+ look at temporal tables

Comment: Yes. Temporal tables and CDC cover this if the version is sufficient

Comment: @khurram - Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` removes the rows, they are not available to view later on.

**Unless** you are using Sql Server 2016+ and then you could use a [System versioned temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table).

You could create an `IsActive` column or something to that effect, and instead of `DELETE` you `UPDATE tbl SET IsActive = 0, dateInactivated = getdate() WHERE...`

Then in your stored procedure you would:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE IsActive = 1
OR (IsActive = 0 AND dateInactivated > @myDate)
```

(EDIT reason: helpful comments below)

Comment: I can't change the table otherwise I could add a field delete with date and time and i could query on delete field if I need to show a record or not.

Comment: This is all covered in temporal tables or CDC

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid & MartinSmith I stand corrected. You two are completely correct and is a viable option for this if the OP is using Sql Server 2016+ [System versioned temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table). I still like my answer considering it is applicable to earlier versions, but thank you for helping me learn something new as well. We are not on 2016 yet at work :/.

Comment: I hear ya! It can be challenging to keep up especially when you're focused on keeping what you've got up and running!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks that I did and found records. Now another problem came up. I pulled all these logs in another table due to the expiry issue of CDC so I could use these logs at any time. Now I have to see my data at any point. Like I had 100 records; I added 10 records today so if I am looking with yesterday date I should see 100, if I see it with now i should see 110, if I remove 5 today I should see them yesterday but not today. Can you help me out making a query which can perform this kind of work.

Comment: At this link https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/ the section under _Retrieve Captured Data of Specific Time Frame_ shows you how to get changes over a particular timeframe. If you take the records from the current table and "subtract" all the inserts that happened over the last 24 hours, you get the table state 24 hours ago. Temporal Tables would probably be easier. To be honest I haven't used either, I'm just aware of them.